# Why collation doesn't work with for xml path in subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I usually use `collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS` to remove accents (diacritics) like this.

```
select ('ěščřžýáíé' + '-' + (select 'ěščřžýáíé')) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS
```

> escrzyaie-escrzyaie

Unfortunately, after one of the search queries stopped working, I found out that collation is ignored when used in combination with `for xml path` in subquery.

```
select ('ěščřžýáíé' + '-' + (select 'ěščřžýáíé' for xml path(''))) 
       collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS
```

> ěščřžýáíé-ěščřžýáíé

It is possible to work around this by using collation for each part separately, but I wonder why it doesn't work in the previous example.

```
select ('ěščřžýáíé' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS + '-' 
     + (select 'ěščřžýáíé' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS for xml path('')))
```

> escrzyaie-escrzyaie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to varchar before concatenating

```
     select ('ěščřžýáíé' + '-' 
             + cast((select 'ěščřžýáíé' for xml path('')) as varchar(max))) 
               collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is needed? I'd like to understand why it doesn't work without it.